# Can I use xcarchive to send my app to a client to be updated on their Apple developer account?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-developer-program

I build an app for a client, and they want to submit the app to apple store using their account. 
The problem is that I'm not registered as a developer under the other company account (I built and tested the app using my personal Apple Developer Account).
Do you think is a good idea send them xcarchive? They can use that archive to sign the code by themselves and submit the app under their account?
Do you have any other idea to solve this issue?

Thanks,

Francesco

Answer (score 1):

I think the problems you are going to hit come from if you're signing the app in the build process.

You can archive your build and then distribute the Archive. (Distribute: Export as Xcode Archive) So that would be the best route as mentioned.

The client should be able to import the archive and then build for Enterprise/AdHoc deployment if the identifier matches their account.

Only the dev account admin can actually push that build to the store and that has a special signing key and cert of its own.

Try marking the project "Don't code sign", archive and see if the client can at least push an adhoc with your archive.

There also should be someone at the client who knows how to build and push an app.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot Archive if you don't sign the code. Another solution could be ask them to send me the distribution profile and the private key. Do you guys have any experience on that? thanks

Comment: Thanks, I thought that you could. In general whenever I do contract work, I get invited into their acct if I'm developing code for them. That way the They can sign as well.